# What triggers 'post-transaction hooks' in pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am curious as to what triggers post-transaction hooks in pacman and whether it is possible to see what hooks are being called for a particular package and with what parameters.

For example, I just installed a custom-build of Wine and there are some errors relating to one of the post-transaction hooks:

```
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/2) Registering binary formats...
/usr/lib/rc/sh/binfmt.sh: line 33: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/: Is a directory
/usr/lib/rc/sh/binfmt.sh: line 35: echo: write error: Invalid argument
binfmt: invalid entry on line 3 of `/usr/lib/binfmt.d/wine.conf'
error: command failed to execute correctly
(2/2) Updating the desktop file MIME type cache...
```

Where can I find exactly what is being called for that binary format hook? Are the hook calls specified somewhere in the PKGBUILD file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find most of the answers in `man 5 alpm-hooks`. There seems to be a bit of disconnect in the documentation and this manual page is only mentioned in the "SEE ALSO" section of the manual pages of `pacman` and `libalpm(3)` (the Arch Linux Package Management (ALPM) library, which pacman is a front end to).

Hooks are specified by `.hook` text files installed by packages themselves in the default directory used by `libalpm`, which is `/usr/share/libalpm/hooks`, or in additional directories listed in `pacman.conf`.

All the hooks whose `TRIGGERS` section(s) includes conditions that match the current `pacman` transaction are run.

The `Exec` directive in each hook's `ACTIONS` section specifies the command to run, including its arguments.

See also the [relevant paragraph](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Hooks) on the Arch Wiki.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!